# ASP.NET Membership - Retrieve Password and PasswordSalt from Membership Table - Hash UserID

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, membership, membership-provider

I am so close to get this project done. I need to retrieve the password and passwordSalt from my Membership table to compare it to my 'OldPasswords' table.

The problem is the Membership provider does not let me use the GetPassword method because the password is hashed.

And I can not retrieve it in a normal sqlConnection because the UserID is hashed also.

Does anyone know how to hash the UserID so I can put it in my where clause?

Or maybe there is a different way to get to that data?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Steve

Comment: What do you have for EnablePasswordRetrieval?

Comment: "the UserID is hashed also" - can you confirm this?

Comment: Here is what that UserID looks like in The Membership table:
e7eaa11e-a6a3-4639-8369-5c507a601bb7, I am not sure if it is encrypted, hashed or a Guid. The Membership documentation is rather sparse.

Comment: Steve - that is a Guid and is what the UserId (ProviderUserKey) should look like. You *are* conflating UserId with UserName.

Comment: Sky - This is the only field, there is no UserName field.

Comment: What table are you looking at? both Users and Membership tables have both UserId (Guid) and UserName/LoweredUserName(string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Steve, the UserId is not hashed. You may be confusing UserName with UserId (ProviderUserKey) which is a Guid.

In the context of your other questions: You should reference this code in both the code that you use to create a new user in order to log the initial password hash, salt and format AND in the OnPasswordChanging so that you can check/reject/insert.

This will get the relevant information for the currently logged in user:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();
var userId = user.ProviderUserKey;

MembershipPasswordFormat passwordFormat;
string passwordSalt;
string password;

var cstring = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localSqlServer"];
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cstring.ConnectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select PasswordFormat,PasswordSalt,Password from aspnet_Membership where UserId=@UserId";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
        conn.Open();
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr != null && rdr.Read())
            {
                passwordFormat = (MembershipPasswordFormat) rdr.GetInt32(0);
                passwordSalt = rdr.GetString(1);
                password = rdr.GetString(2);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("An unhandled exception of type 'DoesntWorkException' has occured");
            }
        }
    }
}

//do something interesting hew with passwordFormat, passwordSalt , password
```

Comment: You code worked great, thank you very much for your help. Once I am completely done I will post all my code. Maybe others find it helpful.

Comment: @Steve - hmm..... a shiny gold check mark next to this and my other answers would help people zero in on the correct answer, eh? ;-)

Comment: Yes of course, sorry, I am still new around here and how this works. Very cool.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be a couple of different things going on here...

- You cannot recover a hashed password.  Period.  The purpose of hashing is to *prevent* exactly this kind of recovery.
- You can hash the User ID for a lookup if the User ID value is already hashed in the database for some reason (although, that is a little strange, there is no good reason to hash a User ID).  But you need to know *how* it was hashed.  If it's MD5 or SHA1, the quickest way is to use [FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.hashpasswordforstoringinconfigfile.aspx) (but use it on the user name instead of the password).
- The salt should *definitely* not be hashed, otherwise it's unusable.  Salts are appended to the clear-text password *before* hashing, so whatever value you see in the salt column *is* the salt.

Comment: Yes, with previous help I was able to finally get the correct hash together to has the password and compare it to my table, BUT now I notice that the username is also scrambled, and using the same hashing function did not work to get a match.

Comment: @steve - the username should not be getting mangled. Something hinky is going on.