# send hashed password to user after registering the user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I modified register usercontrol with my custom fields. In this control it doesn't have password field. I am generating password randomly with `Membership.GeneratePassowrd()` method. I am sending email to the user after registering using `Membership.Getuser(username).GetPassword()` method.Every thing is fine when i kept the `PassowrdFormat=Clear` in web.config file. Now i want to change to `passwordFormat=Hashed`.  But if i use the passwordFormat as `Hased` then it is unable to retrieve the password. Bottom line is i want to send the password to the user which is hashed one. What is the workaround for this one. I am searching in google, but no suitable answers were found. It would be great full if any one give your helping hand. 
I followed these [link1](http://www.communitymx.com/content/source/35F1B/), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741917/asp-net-membership-retrieve-password-and-passwordsalt-from-membership-table) but didn't give any solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you cannot retrieve the password when it is hashed? It is just a column in the table. Are you trying to store the hashed password but send the cleartext password to the user?

Comment: Yes. I want to send password in the clear text format. Stored password is hashed format

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware it's not possible to derive the plain text password from the hashed password stored in the database. If you need to send the plain text password via e-mail then you will need to keep track of it separately.

Depending on how your code is written it could just be as straightforward as saving the result of [Membership.GeneratePassword()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx) to a string variable and ensuring you send that in the e-mail and not any password values retrieved from the database.